# Repeating capture group capability

Tags: regex, greedy

I am trying to repeat a capture group for the text

`a b c d`

desired output is `a` `b` `c` `d`.

I tried to repeat a capture group like so `([A-z])(?:(?:[ ]([A-z]))*)` to get the desired results, but the capture group only keeps the last match. Is regex unable to retain the results of a capture group for repeated captures? If so, does that mean that there is no way for me to capture data like the above of variable length in one regex? Thanks.

Comment: What is the programming language / regex flavor?

Comment: `(.)(\1)`? kind of thing? Match a char followed by another char of the same value?

Comment: I am almost sure there is no need in these repeated groups, you can just match multiple occurrences with `(?i)[a-z]`

Comment: I am using Go `regexp`

Comment: Good, then you do not have access to repeated groups. What is your real problem? Splitting a string into characters is really not a problem.

Comment: If you could get by using another engine, one that supports the `\G` construct, you could use this `(?:\G|^(?:(?!\w[ ]).)*)(\w)(?:[ ]|$)` in a find all way and it will give the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ony *Dot-Net* can get it all in a single match regex.
They are called a capture collection.

Basically, each group will accumulate an array of string's as it goes.

For example,

```
 (?:
      ( [a-zA-Z] )                         # (1)
      (?: [ ] | $ )
 )+
```

in a single match, group 1 contains a  *Collection* of strings.

---

Otherwise, in other engines, the behavior is as you describe,
the capture group is overwritten in each quantified pass.

Comment: Not only .NET can do that.

Comment: Oh yeah, what else does that?

Comment: Boost and Python PyPi regex module. At least. In Perl6, there is a special quantifier that processes repeated groups.

Comment: Don't know about Python, I doubt it though. For sure Boost::regex _does not_ do this.

Comment: You check. I use boost every day, it doesn't do it (if that's what you mean).

Comment: And Perl6 is like Python's _regex_ .. it will never be finalized, and not viable.